# Get file directory in Apache Velocity Template Language

Tags: c++, apache, velocity, clion, vtl

CLion uses Apache's Velocity Template Language (VTL) to create templates for C++ and C files.
On CLion's help (https://www.jetbrains.com/help/clion/file-template-variables.html) a bunch of variables that can be used are listed.

I was wondering however, if it would be possible to use the directory where a C++ file is created as a variable in one of my templates?
I'm asking this because I like to structure my source files in a java/package-type fashion.

All files in the "Utils" directory are part of the "Utils" namespace, all packages in the "Ui" Directory are part of the "Ui" namespace etc...

So I was wondering if there's any way for me to obtain the parent directory of a file so I can use it in a template? (Maybe by setting a variable in my `CMakeLists.txt`?)

Here's an example of what I'd like to achieve

```
#parse("C File Header.h")
#[[#ifndef]]# ${INCLUDE_GUARD}
#[[#define]]# ${INCLUDE_GUARD}

${NAMESPACES_OPEN}
namespace ${CWD}

class ${NAME}
{

};

${NAMESPACES_CLOSE}

#[[#endif]]# //${INCLUDE_GUARD}
```

where `${CWD}` represents the folder the file is in.

The `${NAMESPACE_OPEN}` and `${NAMESPACE_CLOSE}` directives seem to be purely symbolic for CLion, their websites lists it as "indicates the beginning/end of a namespace block created during refactoring."

Comment: Wish this had an answer, not sure why this is so difficult to find

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm happy to announce that this has been fixed in [CLion 2019.1](https://blog.jetbrains.com/clion/2019/03/clion-2019-1-embedded-dev-clangformat-memory-view/)

By going to `File` -> `Settings` -> `Editor` -> `Code Style` -> `C/C++` -> `Naming Conventions` the user can use some extra varibles `${PROJECT_REL_PATH}`, `${FILE_NAME}`, `${EXT}`.

When using this, make sure to also check `File` -> `Settings` -> `Editor` -> `File and Code Templates`. The include guard you defined previously can be accessed here by using the `${INCLUDE_GUARD}` variable.

Here's an example project and configuration to illustrate:

`File` -> `Settings` -> `Editor` -> `File and Code Templates`:

```
#parse("C File Header.h")
#[[#ifndef]]# ${INCLUDE_GUARD}
#[[#define]]# ${INCLUDE_GUARD}

${NAMESPACES_OPEN}

class ${NAME} {

};

${NAMESPACES_CLOSE}

#[[#endif]]# //${INCLUDE_GUARD}
```

`File` -> `Settings` -> `Editor` -> `Code Style` -> `C/C++` -> `Naming Conventions`:

```
${PROJECT_REL_PATH}_${FILE_NAME}_${EXT}
```

Project Structure:

```
Project
├── CMakeLists.txt
├── cpp
│   ├── Test2.cpp
│   └── Test2.hpp
├── main.cpp
├── Test.cpp
└── Test.hpp
```

This gives a "Test.hpp" that looks like this:

```
//
// Created by user on 4/15/19.
//

#ifndef _TEST_HPP
#define _TEST_HPP


class test
{

};


#endif //_TEST_HPP
```

and a Test2.hpp of:

```
//
// Created by user on 4/15/19.
//

#ifndef CPP_TEST2_HPP
#define CPP_TEST2_HPP


class test2
{

};


#endif //CPP_TEST2_HPP
```

Comment: Your answer helped me but. How could I capitalize the ${NAME}?